# How to decode route parameters in Sinatra?

Tags: parameters, routes, sinatra, decode

I have implemented a simple route :

```
get '/test' do
    params
end
```

When I call it without encoded parameters like

```
/test?plip=plop
=> ["plip", "plop"]
```

I am able to retrieve my parameter without any problem.

However, with encoded parameters :

```
/test?plip%3Dplop
=> ["plip=plop", nil]
```

the key/value does not match anymore.
Do we have any solution to solve this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: why are you encoding them?

Comment: In fact, I don't need to encode them but just in case I receive encoded parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since query values can be encoded (and should if they contain characters that affect the parsing) then there shouldn't be a time when the app receives an `=` as a `%3D` that is meant to be part of the query string and not simply a query value. [Rack](https://github.com/rack/rack) handles parsing of query strings for you, so all you need to worry about is whether, in your example, the *value* of `params["plip"]` needs to be decoded, but I don't think you even need to worry about that, as the following example shows:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  params.inspect
end
```

I get a CGI encoded string via IRB:

```
URI.encode "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987085/how-to-decode-route-parameters-in-sinatra"
=> "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987085/how-to-decode-route-parameters-in-sinatra"
```

and then I run the app and check the output (note, there are some extra escape characters in the `curl` calls for my terminal, they're removed when `curl` is run so ignore those):

```
$ curl http://localhost:4567/
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Mar/2015:12:10:03 +0900] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2 0.0045
localhost - - [14/Mar/2015:12:10:03 JST] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2
- -> /
{}%   

$ curl http://localhost:4567/\?plip\=plop
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Mar/2015:12:10:25 +0900] "GET /?plip=plop HTTP/1.1" 200 16 0.0005
localhost - - [14/Mar/2015:12:10:25 JST] "GET /?plip=plop HTTP/1.1" 200 16
- -> /?plip=plop

$ curl http://localhost:4567/\?plip\=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F28987085%2Fhow-to-decode-route-parameters-in-sinatra
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Mar/2015:12:11:51 +0900] "GET /?plip=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F28987085%2Fhow-to-decode-route-parameters-in-sinatra HTTP/1.1" 200 98 0.0005
localhost - - [14/Mar/2015:12:11:51 JST] "GET /?plip=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F28987085%2Fhow-to-decode-route-parameters-in-sinatra HTTP/1.1" 200 98
- -> /?plip=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F28987085%2Fhow-to-decode-route-parameters-in-sinatra
{"plip"=>"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987085/how-to-decode-route-parameters-in-sinatra"}%
```

As you can see from the final output, the incoming parameter has been decoded for you:

`{"plip"=>"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987085/how-to-decode-route-parameters-in-sinatra"}%`

Comment: I think you are right. The "=" should not be encoded.  In this case, I don't have problem anymore. :) Thanks for your help.

Comment: @M07 glad to be of help.